# Accessing Jira Cloud using Unirest Java libraries

Tags: httpclient, jira, unirest

I would like to use Unirest Java libraries for accessing Jira Cloud.
Can you share any code snippets? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the Unirest dependency to your pom.xml (for Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use the following syntax to query JIRA Cloud. Replace yourjira with your instance name and replace with your username and password.

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response  = Unirest.get("https://yourjira.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=").basicAuth("username","password").asJson();
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

More specific JIRA Cloud REST API syntax can be found here:
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/

Comment: Its working precisely. Thank you so much, it is much simpler than the Jersey client.